# Rewrite code using function definition and prototype

Tags: c++, function, prototype

I have a source code for school which is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int a[12] = { 1, 5, 3, 9, 13, 17, -3, 6, 99, 10, 18, 22 };
    int v, i;
    int truth;
    cin >> v;

    for (i = 0; i<12; i++)
        if (v == a[i])
            truth = 1;
    cout << endl;

    (truth) ? (cout << "Present\n") : (cout << "Not present\n");

    system("pause");
}
```

How can I rewrite the code including the for loop, which checks if v is present in the array, into a function and writing its prototype?

**Update**

Figured out, thanks to ThomasMatthews, how to use declaration of function and then figured it out how to use arguments for the function:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int checking(int x[], int);

int main(void) {
    int a[12] = { 1, 5, 3, 9, 13, 17, -3, 6, 99, 10, 18, 22 };
    int myNumber;
    cin >> myNumber;
    int myCondition = checking(a, myNumber);

    (myCondition) ? (cout << "Present\n") : (cout << "Not present\n");
    system("pause");
}

int checking(int x[], int z) {
    int i, myCondition = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        if (z == x[i]) {
            myCondition = 1;
        }
    }
    return myCondition;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be outsourcing the questioner's homework rather than solving any specific problem

Comment: It is not a homework, however I am trying to understand how prototypes and function definitions work.

Comment: I highly recommend reading the section about *functions* in your favorite reference.

Comment: You should do your homework yourself, you cannot learn anything as doing someones and stackoverflow exists for helping your own codes.

Comment: BTW, the `main` *function* returns `int`.  Always.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, a function *declaration* is *how* to call the function.

A function *definition* is the code that is executed for the function.

An example declaration:

```
int main(void);
```

An example function definition:

```
int main(void)
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Similarly, you could do:

```
void print_hello(void); // Declaration
int main(void)
{
  print_hello();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void print_hello(void)
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since we're in C++-land, the `void`s aren't needed.

Comment: I know, but I like to be explicit. :-)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It's not being *explicit*: a function with no parameters as no parameters. (void) exist in C++ to allow from-C headers portability, not for C++ itself. You are not making explicit a default: you are disguising a C++ prototype to make it C-ish.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thank you, I think I figured it out. I just had difficulties understanding what arguments should I add to the function, and I figured it out that the "truth" argument was not needed, as the function itself would return the value I need to check in the if statement. I will post the result I needed.